# Historical Hurricane Tracks

Tags: data

I have found a great source for historical hurricane data, but I can't seem to find a way to download the track information.  It appears that you can only view the data on the website.  I was wondering if anyone else has had this issue, and if anyone knows a way to get access to the data (either as a .shp or .kml).

Here's the website: http://www.csc.noaa.gov/hurricanes/#

---

Yes I did see this, I was hoping there was some data already made.  Wishful thinking.  Guess I will make the files.

Comment: After a little more digging I found a place that has the data as a shapefile.  http://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/oa/ibtracs/index.php?name=ibtracs-data

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you see the Download button in the upper-right corner?  http://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/oa/ibtracs/index.php?name=wmo-data

Comment: in 2020, this 404s...

Answer (score 4):

If you click on the download link in the top right it takes you to [this page](http://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/oa/ibtracs/index.php?name=wmo-data) which allows the download of data in a number of formats, including csv, from which you can parse the data into a shapefile using the gis of your choice (or python).

Answer (score 3):

As of 2018-09-25 the links listed above all point to 404 errors.  I have found downloadable (FGDB format) historic tracks (1900-2013) at:

https://coast.noaa.gov/digitalcoast/data/

Search for the phrase "Tropical Cyclone Storm Segments", then click the Download button, which takes you to an ftp site:

ftp://ftp.coast.noaa.gov/pub/MSP/TropicalCycloneExposure.zip